# Pipe with exposition of variables magrittr

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I am trying to understand how the magrittr exposition operator `%$%` works.
I read that the usage should be similar to the `with` function, however it doesn't behave as expected.
I don't understand why in this example it returns an error

```
> with(iris, sum(Sepal.Length)/sum(Sepal.Width))
[1] 1.911252
> iris %$% sum(Sepal.Length) / sum(Sepal.Width)
Error: object 'Sepal.Width' not found
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Operator precedence? Put parentheses around the ratio of sums.

Comment: did you try that Artem?

Comment: yep..this works. `iris %$% {sum(Sepal.Length) / sum(Sepal.Width)}`

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much. Why curly braces?

Comment: curly braces* make expressions

Comment: Was/am on my phone, so couldn't try any code. Glad to see curly brackets worked.